# Openlayers 6, App crashes when I set too many text labels

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I'm looking for an efficient way to set conditionally text for over 3000 features. Below is a little code on how I do it now, but my Android App freezes and crashes sometimes because it exceeds the memory limit of 2 GB. I did try to cache my styles first by color but I end up with only two styles for every feature so I can't set text individually. I did notice that, when I set the text font size to 24px, my app crashes on start, when I return the style function, because of that I set the font size to 18 px.

```
var layer = new ol.layer.VectorImage({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: function(feature) {
                style.getFill().setColor(getColorByID(feature.get('id'), feature.get('pe_nr')));
                return style;
            }
});


var style = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'black',
    width: 1
  }),
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    font: '18px Calibri,sans-serif',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'black'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'white',
      width: 0.5
    })
  })
});


function switchLabel(label) {

    if(label == 'a'){
        currentLabel = 'a';
    } else if (label == 'b') {
        currentLabel = 'b';
    } else {
        currentLabel = '';
    }
    
    var vectorLayer;
    var layersObject = map.getLayers();
    for (var i = 0; i < layersObject.array_.length; i++) {
        vectorLayer = layersObject.array_[i];
        break;
    }
    
    if(isFoo){
        vectorLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
        style.getText().setText(feature.get(currentLabel));
        style.getFill().setColor(getColor(feature.get('pe_nr')));
        return style;
        });
    } else {
        vectorLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
        style.getText().setText(feature.get(currentLabel));
        style.getFill().setColor(getColorByID(feature.get('id'), feature.get('pe_nr')));
        return style;
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: It was a bug in Openlayers: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/10527